# A capitular letter in a font different than the text

Tags: fonts, chapters, fontsize

How can I make a capitular letter in a different font of that one used in the main text? I mean, I'd like to do something like this (image made in paint):

[image]

Thank you very much, guys!

Comment: Take a look at the [`lettrine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) package.